# System dead after update and reboot

Tags: command-line, server, raid, crash

So I rebooted my system after an update and upgrade. Now my raid is missing, all of my network settings, programs, etc are "missing" I think they are all in the missing raid. I have to use ip to add an ip and dgw before the system will come online. My username doesn't seem to exist anymore so I have to use root to sign in. My home directory is in the raid for sure.

Not really sure what else to say. When I try to install software I get error status 1 with no real output. I didn't see anything helpful in the logs. Any ideas? I have literally my whole life of files on there (7TB) so I'd rather not lose them if I can help it. That's all I really  care about.

Ubuntu server latest lts,

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

update

---

I have gotten my profile back now and the raid is assembling and mounting. I can connect to the net by using dhclient -r && dhclient

now when I try to update I get

Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'

---

update

---

Went into tty mode and force removed python, left tty and ran dpkg --configure -a (no errors) then I ran update but got a python error. Installed python again and updated, had 900+ packages that need updates now (they didn't before all this) and so far they have been running alright.

However; I did get this message and I assume it has something to do with the root cause.

```
│ The GRUB boot loader was previously installed to a disk that is no longer present, or whose unique identifier has changed for some reason. It is important to make sure that the installed GRUB core image stays in sync with GRUB   │
  │ modules and grub.cfg. Please check again to make sure that GRUB is written to the appropriate boot devices.                                                                                                                          │
  │                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
  │ GRUB install devices:
```

Comment: Latest is not a version of Ubuntu an exact version needs to be stated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to reconfigure the installed packages with

- sudo dpkg --configure -a

Check if the user still exist with something like

- awk -F: '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd
  And check your files
- ls /home/$USER (write your username if your are connected with root)

Check the network settings in the file /etc/networks/interfaces. If it doesn't exist create one from an internet sample and run:

- sudo systemctl start networking

Comment: User account does exist and after another reboot I am able to sign into it. (All of my files in raid are still missing) but the account exists and is signing in. As for dpkg --configure -a I tried that earlier and again after the reboot but it just says there was an error configuring (every package) As for start networking, "service not found".

Comment: I have gotten my profile back now and the raid is assembling and mounting. I can connect to the net by using dhclient -r && dhclient

now when I try to update I get 

 Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'